# Correct use of MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT?

Tags: java, android, motionevent

I would like to be notified when the pointer is out of the boundary of a View. So I set the listener like this :

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT) {
               // Notify
            }
        }
```

However, this doesn't work. Any ideas please? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation it should be delivered to

```
    View.onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent)
```

rather than

```
    View.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)
```